# Состояние объекта в Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как можно сохранить текущее состояние объекта, чтобы его можно было загрузить? Например, в течение игры компоненты меняют свои параметры, причем компонентов может быть слишком много, и нужно сделать так, чтобы при смерти игрока все компоненты возвращали себе исходное состояние. Возможно ли это реализовать? Если да, то как?

Comment: что подразумевается под компонентами? о каком состоянии идет речь?

Answer (score 0):

Для сохранения текущего состояния объектов используется сериализация (и десериализация как обратный процесс). Хранить сериализованный объект можно в памяти, в файле или в базе данных.
Тема достаточно обширная, начать можно с [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms233843(v=vs.100).aspx).